# get random arabic letters of string

Tags: php, arabic

I have this code that take the word and randomize the letters
it works fine with english letters but with arabic it does not work fine

```
<?php

$str = 'علي';
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);
$arr1 = str_split($shuffled);



foreach($arr1 as $bessah){
   echo $bessah.'<br />'; 


 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because they don't work with unicode (multi byte character). From this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

A proper unicode string split;

```
<?php
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
?>
```

And here's for str_shuffle (taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php):

```
<?php
function str_shuffle_unicode($str) {
    $tmp = preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    shuffle($tmp);
    return join("", $tmp);
}
?>
```

Example:

```
$str = '日本語';
$shuffled = str_shuffle_unicode($str);
$arr1 = str_split_unicode($shuffled);
```

Output:
語
本
日

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm pretty sure. I added the str_shuffle() replacement. You can check the original pages for example or just try them.

Comment: i did not know how to use the first function please explaine how to use it

Comment: @johnj just replace str_shuffle with str_shuffle_unicode and str_split with str_split_unicode. I added an example.